# printf stops flushing the buffer after execvp in the child process

Tags: c, printf, fork, execvp

Now I know this issue is pretty common but trust me, I don't know why this particular case is happening.

Basically, I am forking my program twice and then running `execvp` inside the second child. I am using `dup2` in child1 to duplicate standard output with the `logfile` file. I am expecting both the child to log all messages into that file.

Here is the pseudo-code of my application.

```
fork();
if(child1){
  // child 1 operations
  int log_fd = open(logfile, O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  dup2(log_fd, 1);
  fork();
  if(child2){
    // child 2 operations
    execvp(executable, params);
  }
  else {
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    // child 1 more operations
  }
}
else{
  // parent operations
}

return 0;
```

So this is the gist of what is happening in my code, the original code is a bit large to share.

Here is the test program for the `executable` which is run by `execvp`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  // setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  printf("pf: started test process\n");
  // std::cout << "co: started test process" << std::endl;
  uint32_t timer = 1;

  while(true){
    // std::cout << "co: tick tick " << timer++ << std::endl;
    printf("pf: tick tick %u\n", timer++);
    // fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is, none of the `printf` statement appears in the `logfile`. However, as you can see the commented statements like 'cout', 'fflush' or 'setvbuf', the print messages start appearing in the `logfile`. I don't understand why `printf` statements are not flushing the buffer.

Another thing which is bothering me is that the printf statements in `child 1 operations` and `child 2 operations` in my application pseudo code is working fine. Only the program run by `execvp` is causing problem. But why?!

---

Extra information

This was the test program which is what I wrote to test if my logic would work before actually developing the application.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  const char* name = "/Users/molecule/tp/cpp/output.log";
  char *const args[] = {"ls", NULL};
  int status;

  printf("start\n");

  if (fork() == 0){
    printf("child\n");
    int fd = open(name, O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    printf("fd %d\n", fd);
    dup2(fd, 1);
    printf("child after dup2\n");

    if(fork() == 0){
      printf("child2\n");
      execvp(args[0], args);
      close(fd);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  else {
    wait(&status);
    printf("status %d\n", status);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is working perfectly fine. The output of `ls` can be seen in the `output.log` file. But I can't figure out what's wrong in my application. Please help me in this agonizing moment.

Comment: Do you say that it works if you use `fflush(stdout)`? And that it works if you use`setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`?

Comment: @klutt yes.. But the executable can be anything. I cannot make sure that every user, using my application calls `fflush` or `setvbuf`

Comment: If standard output is a file, stdio usually fully buffers the stream, so I would't expect to see anything until the child program has produced enough output to fill up the internal buffer and cause an automatic flush.

Comment: Hey @Shawn. But then why does it work in the program which I have posted in the end? You can run and check it mate.

Comment: If you change what the underlying file descriptor refers to after already writing to stdout, the stdio functions aren't going to notice that it changed from a terminal to a file and alter their behavior accordingly.

Comment: And when `ls` exits, it flushes any open streams. Your other program has an infinite loop so that won't happen.

Comment: @Shawn.. then why does `std::cout` statements work correctly ? and only `printf` is causing problem. ? Also, why are `printf` statements before `execvp` working correctly.

Comment: Because you have a `std::endl` in it. Do you know what that does?

Comment: @Shawn yes it flushes the buffer. I got what you are saying. The flushing of the buffer for `printf` won't behave the same when it is not linked to the command line. Thanks for the help.